# using nulls in a mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, null, mysqli, prepared-statement

In a mysqli prepared statement, a NULL gets turned into '' (in the case of a string) or 0 (in the case of an integer). I would like to store it as a true NULL.  Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: I can't believe how long I've struggled with this, and the answer was almost obvious. Strictly: you can't. Structurally: bind_param. By code: `$query_param_01 = (null===$param_01) ? "?" : "NULL";` +1 to everyone. (I'll stick with `{$query_param_01}` as there's still no injection issues. Feel free to correct.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's possible to bind a true NULL value to the prepared statements (read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96148)).

> You can, in fact, use mysqli_bind_parameter to pass a NULL value to the database. simply create a variable and store the NULL value (see the manpage for it) to the variable and bind that. Works great for me anyway.

Thus it'll have to be something like:

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

    // person is some object you have defined earlier
    $name = $person->name();
    $age = $person->age();
    $nickname = ($person->nickname() != '') ? $person->nickname() : NULL;

    // prepare the statement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Name, Age, Nickname VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param('sis', $name, $age, $nickname);
?>
```

This should insert a NULL value into the database.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I needed to know, just made it a bit more generic:
`foreach($param as $k => $v) { if($v == '') $param[$k] = NULL; }`, so basically any null entry is converted to a true NULL, carefull with nested arrays though, just make it recursive if ur using those^^
This should be the selected answer though, thks

Answer (score 48):

For anyone coming looking at this because they are having problems binding NULL in their `WHERE` statement, the solution is this:

There is a mysql [NULL safe operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) that must be used:

`<=>`

Example:

```
<?php
$price = NULL; // NOTE: no quotes - using php NULL
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM product WHERE price <=> ?"); // Will select products where the price is null
$stmt->bind_param($price);
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The comments to the [PHP documentation on `mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt-bind-param) indicate that passing in `NULL` was not easily possible.

---

> Please see @creatio's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6892491/18771

---

Solutions offered in the comments do some pre-preparation work on the prepared statement, replacing the `"?"` markers with `"NULL"` for every param that has the PHP `null` value. The modified query string is then used.

The following function is from [user comment 80119](http://de.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#80119):

```
function preparse_prepared($sQuery, &$saParams)
{
    $nPos = 0;

    $sRetval = $sQuery;
    foreach ($saParams as $x_Key => $Param)
    {
        //if we find no more ?'s we're done then
        if (($nPos = strpos($sQuery, '?', $nPos + 1)) === false)
        {
            break;
        }

        //this test must be done second, because we need to 
        //increment offsets of $nPos for each ?.
        //we have no need to parse anything that isn't NULL.
        if (!is_null($Param))
        {
            continue;
        }


        //null value, replace this ? with NULL.
        $sRetval = substr_replace($sRetval, 'NULL', $nPos, 1);

        //unset this element now
        unset($saParams[$x_Key]);
    }
    return $sRetval;
}
```

*(It's not really the coding style I would have done it in, but if it works...)*

Comment: FWIW, this breaks on "WHERE column_name != ?" because comparisons to NULL are always NULL.  This also breaks on "WHERE question = 'et tu, brute?'"

Answer (score -2):

I store all parameters in an array and pass them in `bind_param` function using `array_shift($myArray)`. NULL is accepted like that.

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE test_NULL (id int(11))");
if($query=$mysqli->prepare("insert into test_NULL VALUES(?)")){
    $query->bind_param('i',$null); //note that $null is undefined
    $query->execute();
}else{
    echo __LINE__.' '.$mysqli->error;
}
?>
```