# MYSQL/PHP How do I insert a null value?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems updating records to contain NULL values - in particular, a field which is of type Date.

I'm using prepared statements and I've tried the following:

```
// Fails
$value = NULL;

// Fails
$value = "";

// Fails
$value = "NULL";
```

all 3 of the above result in a date of 1969-12-31 being entered (0). How do I insert NULL values?

Comment: What does the definition for your table look like?  May you insert a NULL value into this field?

Comment: Yes, it allows null values. If I go into PHP my admin I can do "update tblA set date_field = NULL" sucessfully, or without prepared statements it works fine.

Comment: you're talking about sql here, so could you please show the query you're using to update the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the following question/answer: [using nulls in a mysqli prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371644/using-nulls-in-a-mysqli-prepared-statement)

That seems to be the same issue. Correct me if I'm wrong?