# I want to assign a NULL value to my column in a database table using the key of an array... how?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

On the following piece of code, i get the following error:

Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt

```
// assign
$title = 'this is the title';
$caption = 'description goes here...';
$filename = '43534b34.jpg';

$thumb = array();
$thumb['basename'] = null;
$thumb['width'] = 0;
$thumb['height'] = 0;

// insert new record in db
$sql = 'INSERT INTO image (title, caption, filename, thumb_filename, thumb_width, thumb_height) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $title, $caption, $filename, $thumb['basename'], $thumb['width'], $thumb['height']);
$stmt->execute();
```

if i replace the key in array like  `$thumb['basename'] = 'test';`, then all is ok!

How do i assign the NULL value to my column in the database table?

Comment: can you paste a mysql describe of the thumb_filename column

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371644/using-nulls-in-a-mysqli-prepared-statement

Comment: user2023235: by the type of question you've asked, i checked if the assign null option was checked... it was not! duh!!! time for a break! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $title, $caption, $filename, empty($thumb['basename']) ? NULL : $thumb['basename'] , $thumb['width'], $thumb['height']);
```