# Using PHP mysqli: where clause in bind_param might be NULL

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a bound query where a column in the where clause might be null or might have a value.

Example code:

```
select
    name
from
    table
where
    typeId = 1
```

Sometimes the query might include a null value i.e.

```
select
    name
from
    table
where
    typeId is null
```

Normally with a bound query, I would do the following:

```
select
    name
from
    table
where
    typeId = ?
```

**However, where typeId is null, I won't get a resultset. Only if I hardcode `typeId is null` will I get a result.
Do you know of a solution or workaround to this?**

FYI, the code for the query is:

```
    $sql = "select name from table where typeId = ?"; 
    $params = array(null);
    $types = array("i");

    $param_refs = array();
    foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
        $param_refs[$key] = &$params[$key];
    }
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);


    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge($types, $param_refs));
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $fields = $result->fetch_fields();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          //code to handle each row of result
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using nulls in a mysqli prepared statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371644/using-nulls-in-a-mysqli-prepared-statement)

Comment: @MrCode I saw that answer, it's not a dupe. The solution is different for an insert compared to a select's where clause. As is indicated by the answer given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<=>` operator

```
$sql = "select name from table where typeId <=> ?";
```